# How to set grant_type as key and value as client_credentials in c# (rest service)

Tags: c#, rest, postman, access-token, webrequest

I have one API which returns a token. Using postman I can get the token details by setting the authorization in the header section. As per the API specs I am selecting the radio button as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set the key value as `grant_type` and value as `client_credentials` in the postman body.

When I try to achieve the same in c# I am not able to figure out how to set the key value `grant_type` and value as `client_credentials`.
Below is my code, when I am running the code I am getting the error.Can anyone assist me in setting the grant_type as key and value as `client_credentials` in `WebRequest`. I have also attached the screen shot.

[image]

`the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on send`

Below is inner exception captured. `{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}`

```
       var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        //request.ContentLength = 0;   // new commented

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        string postData = "grant_type=client_credentials"; // Not sure if we can set the values like this
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TokenAuthorizationKey").ToString());

        request.Timeout = 600000;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();  // this Line throws Error
        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);

                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            return responseValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like below,

```
var requestparams = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
                };
 string postData = string.Join("&", requestparams.Select(kv => kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value).ToArray());
```

This way you can append your request params in your body, This should work

Comment: Getting the same error. `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.`.This is the line which throws the error `Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

Answer (score 0):

I was using RestSharp but wanted to go back to "basics".

I used your postdata and incorporated it into my code and it worked

'String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(strUserID + ":" + strPwd));

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strURL);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Concat("Basic ", encoded));
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.Method = "POST";

        string strPostData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(strPostData);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        using (Stream objStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream))
            {
                var objText = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                strRawOP = string.Concat(strRawOP, Environment.NewLine, (objText).ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(strRawOP);
```

'